# How do you get python Pandas to respect matplotlib arguments when running via IPython Notebook on a VM?

Tags: python, pandas, vagrant, jupyter-notebook

I have installed pandas and IPython Notebook, and am running on a Vagrant box. When plotting and attempting to create a stacked bar graph on a data frame, pandas ignores secondary arguments passed to the `plot()` function.

I don't know whether this is due to my enviornment, version of pandas, or a basic error in usage of the plotting syntax.

To replicate you can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/elifesciences/elife-template-env) to install a Vagrant box running IPython.

Python libraries that are installed in this route are:

```
Chef python cookbook python', '>= 1.2.2 
requests==0.13.0","lxml","beautifulsoup4","fom","lettuce","boto","nose
ipython-notebook
python-scipy
python-matplotlib
python-pandas
python-sympy
```

No version numbers are specified, so I am assuming that the latest and greatest are installed.

After installation I run IPython via `ipython notebook --ip=192.168.33.11 -pylab inline`. I open the notebook on that IP, and then I try

```
import pylab as pl
from pandas import *
x = DataFrame({"Alpha": Series({1: 1, 2: 3, 3:2.5}), "Beta": Series({1: 2, 2: 2, 3:3.5})})
x.plot(kind="bar")
```

This works as expected, but

```
x.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

produces exactly the same plot, rather than one with stacked bars. I expected to see a stacked bar chart.

Comment: I think this would be better as an [issue](https://github.com/elifesciences/elife-template-env/issues) on githib. Your code works fine with regular ipython notebook...

Comment: thanks, I've raised an issue on the IPython project https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3256